# What does 24 have to do with anything?

Tags: riddle, knowledge

Novice shipwright, seafarer, navigator.

I live in a land removed,

Yet my ancestors came from yours.

My wife's name is a flower and sick,

My tutor was straight out of old times,

And my son swapped my protein structure prediction with a small stream(that didn't have doubled).

I was the first one who they saw, an old friend.

But left because of the great time rift.

Welcome to the painting, friends and company

Comment: cant stop thinking about something related to DNA ;)

Comment: _My tutor was straight out of old times, And my son swapped my protein structure prediction with a small stream_ woah, that escalated quickly!

Comment: @user Same. Even though Ik it's Narnia now lol.

Comment: 24 is 42 backwards...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is

> Prince Caspian

and given AJL's note in comments, I guess that 24 means

> the 24th letter of the alphabet -- X, since he is King Caspian X.
>  Although it makes my brain hurt to interpret a Roman numeral that way.

Novice shipwright, seafarer, navigator.

> The plot of Voyage of the Dawn Treader

I live in a land removed,

Yet my ancestors came from yours.

> Caspian lives in Narnia which is populated with humans.  More specifically as rand al'thor said in comments, "Caspian is a Telmarine, descended from pirates who slipped from this world into the world of Narnia."

My wife's name is a flower and sick,

> In the books she has no name, but in the movie it is Lilliandill (lily and ill)

My tutor was straight out of old times,

> His tutor Doctor Cornelius was part dwarf and thus from an older race than the humans.  Also he told Caspian many things about the old times

And my son swapped my protein structure prediction with a small stream(that didn't have doubled).

> This is just saying that the name Rilian is like Caspian with "casp" (http://predictioncenter.org/casproll/index.cgi - CASP ROLL - obviously the author just googled CASP and took something) replaced with "ril" ("rill" = a small stream, without the double "l")

I was the first one who they saw, an old friend.

> In The Silver Chair, Jill and Eustace are supposed to greet the first person they see, who is an old friend.  Eustace sees Caspian first...

But left because of the great time rift.

> ... but Caspian sails away unrecognized because Eustace doesn't recognize him since it's been many years in Narnia (though not in England).

Welcome to the painting, friends and company

> In Voyage of the Dawn Treader the kids get to Narnia through a painting.

Comment: You just have to figure out about the ancestors and 24 ;-)

Comment: Ah, brilliant! I thought this sounded like something I'd read, but couldn't pin it down. Kudos to @AJL and Daphne B :-)

Comment: Re. ancestors, Caspian is a Telmarine, descended from pirates who slipped from this world into the world of Narnia. @AJL No clue about the Caspian Sea then? :-(

Comment: 24 could be because Caspian is in books 2 to 4. I dont think he's in any of the others and he isn't in the first. (Publication order not the chronological order)

Comment: Yes @rand but no to Spacemonkey

Comment: @Daphne It's been a while.... But the 24 refers to one aspect of said character that is strangely absent.

Comment: Caspian isn't the 24th king of Narnia.  He isn't the 24th king named Caspian.  He isn't the 24th-to-last king of Narnia (as far as I could tell).  His 24th birthday isn't mentioned specifically.  There aren't 24 territories in Narnia.  So I'm stumped.

Comment: http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=gRFVDvk7C94 is all I could think of lolol

Comment: Perhaps try something with letters and numbers, it's actually a bit simpler than you think.

Comment: Hooray!  Good job :) (I know it's a bit weird to convert numbers into roman numerals into different numbers)